# Delphi read file at specific address

Tags: delphi

This question is very basic because I am at a very basic level. I have to read the contents of a file with a `*.pam` extension. It's not common, that's a file generated by a specific program and it has a fixed size of xx KB. There are some numbers and values inside it.

I need to read this file and so I am going to use `TStreamReader`. Of course I need to know the structure of the file but I don't. By the way I have the picture above that is a part of a table with useful info:

[image]

The meaning is the following: once you've opened the file, go to a specific address and get the data. For example, in 0x30 I can find the data about 'Move 1 Current PP'. My question is: how do I jump to a given address?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var sw: TStreamReader;
begin

 Memo1.Clear;    
 sw := TStreamReader.Create('C:\aaa\myfile.pam', TEncoding.UTF8);
 try

  sw.Position := 0;

 finally
  sw.Free;
 end;
```

I have seen in the documentation that there is something like `Seek` and `Position` but it seems that I cannot use them. In general I would use

```
while not(sw.EndOfStream) do
 begin
  //read...
 end;
```

This starts from the beginning and it reads the data in seqence. How can I jump to a specific address and read the content? I guess that I can pass the hex address to a function like Seek, so I can go to a specific point. Then I can just retrieve the data.

Comment: `TStreamReader` is a helper class for reading textual data. Your file is not text, it is binary. Use `TFileStream` directly instead, then you can use `Seek`/`Position`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file content is binary (as opposite to textual) do not use any kind of text encoding options.

In the following example I use `TFileStream` to handle the file and to read selected parts of the file. The `procedure ReadBuffer()` method has overloads that takes either an untyped buffer or a buffer of type `TBytes`. It raises an `EReadError` exception if requested number of bytes can not be read.

```
var
  fn: TFileName;
  fs: TFileStream;
  b: byte;
  bf: array[0..3] of word;
  ReadResult: integer;
begin
  fn := 'c:\tmp\MyMagicalFile.pam';
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    fs.Seek($28, soFromBeginning);    // move to offset $28 in the file
    fs.ReadBuffer(bf, 8);             // read 4 x 2 bytes into buffer (bf)
                                      // fs.Position is at this point at $30
    fs.ReadBuffer(b, 1);              // read one byte (at offset $30) into the buffer (b)
  finally
    fs.free;
  end;
  // use b and bf as needed
end;
```

As in the code above, you jump to a given position in the file by using the `Seek()` method. The position is automatically updated when reading (or writing). `SeekOptions` are `soFromBeginning`, `soFromCurrent` and `soFromEnd`.
 For other details see [System.Classes.TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TFileStream).

Comment: Thank you very much, you have saved my day Tom ;) the "documentation" of the file says that the data are stored in little endian so I guess that jumping as you do it perfectly fine. Am I correct?

Comment: You might be interested in [TBinaryReader](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBinaryReader).

Comment: Thanks @Victoria for the notification. Admittedly this has slipped by somehow, probably because I have my library from past years with similar functionality. I guess it was added sometime XE..XE3, which I did not install. It exists in XE4

Comment: This is not generic enough it is for a certain path ('c:\tmp\MyMagicalFile.pam';)