# Delphi open files with streams

Tags: delphi

I asked some days ago [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548492/delphi-read-file-at-specific-address) question in which people told me to use `TFileStream`. I am reading Głowacki's Expert Delphi and he uses TStreamReader/TStreamWriter. In a comment I have read this:

> TStreamReader is a helper class for reading textual data. Your file is
>   not text, it is binary. Use TFileStream directly instead

I'm a bit in trouble with this. I understand that a [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) file does not contain text and to with `TFileStream` I can read binaries (as the documentation says). Let's say that I want to use `TStreamWriter` to output a series of numbers on a file and then read the content of this file. Am I allowed to do it with a TFileStream?

I see that TStreamWriter has the `TEncoding` in the constructor so I need to specify utf-8 or ansi for example. Does this affect the structure of the file?

I am new with this and I don't really understand the expert topics I've found online. From what I've understood TFileStream is for binary files and TStreamReader is for files that has some text inside

Comment: For binary files you can use [TBinaryReader](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBinaryReader) and [TBinaryWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBinaryWriter) helper classes.

Comment: @Victoria thank you :) The fact is that I see a lot of classes that can be used to read files and I don't know how to choose the correct one

Comment: Those classes are just helpers. They help you to store and read what you want. For example [TStreamWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) reference says about its purpose _"Writer for characters to stream."_ If you don't want to write only characters, don't use it. [TBinaryWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBinaryWriter) _"Use TBinaryWriter to write primitive data types to a stream as binary values in a specific encoding."_ so if you want to write e.g. integers (but even strings), it can help you...

Comment: Any data you can write and read with a [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFileStream). Just the syntax will is less readable than with those helpers. But might be more efficient, because unlike those helper classes, with [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFileStream) you can write and read e.g. an array of integers at once.

Comment: @Victoria So with TFileStream I can read everything, the others are just specific to something to let me read/write stuff on a file in a easier way. Correct? :)

Comment: Exactly like that :)

Comment: @Emma What files are these .pam files? What do they contain? (if not a secret)

Comment: Numbers don't have to be text. You're being unclear about your intent. Are the numbers expected to be readable if a user opens the file in a text editor like Notepad? If so, you're writing text. If not, you write binary. Binary files hold information that isn't meaningful to a person who sees it, but makes sense to software (like an image file, or an executable file, or a data file that is designed to be used by an application, or a Word document). If the class you want to use asks for an encoding, it's for text. Binary files don't have that option. That should help make it clearer.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a TAsciiArtStreamWriter!  ;-)

Comment: @TomBrunberg just a series of IDs of products. They are all integers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not trying to confuse you, but in fact all files are binary.

They contain a number of bytes, and how these bytes are interpreted by humans or by software makes them useful.

But if the terms **text** and **binary** are opposed, then **text** means (more or less) anything that is human readable, like this answer, while **binary** means anything that is not text.

An example: in current Delphi versions, an **integer** is made up of four bytes. If you store these bytes directly to a file, you are writing binary. If you write the text form (e.g. `-172423423`) as characters, then you are writing text.

A `TextWriter` writes text to a stream. The `TBinaryWriter` writes data as it is stored in memory. Both can use any kind of stream, be it a `TFileStream` or a `TMemoryStream` to write to (or read from). The stream represents a file or some other writable medium.

Text, these days, can have many encodings, e.g. UTF-8, several Ansi codepages, etc. This means that "characters" that are not in the range `#0..#127` are encoded differently. This can, of course, change the exact contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks Rudy I have understood ;) you didn't confuse me I had understood that all files are binary. Your answer cleared my ideas